# Extending LatinIME

Tags: android, android-source

I want to extend android's default IME, LatinIME. I cloned LatinIME's Android 2.1 tag from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME), but there are some issues with the code.

For example in the class `CandidateView` the variable `mScrollX` is used, which is part of `View`, the extended class. But turns out that with the public SDK, that variable is private so it can't be used by children classes.

What I found in Google to be the solution to this is to change the use of `mScrollX` for the public getters of `View`, but the code also sets that variable and there are no setters available.

Another issue is that `com.android.internal.R` is used, which also isn't public available.

How am I supposed to extend LatinIME? Has anyone tried to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int scrollX = getScrollX();
```